# JodaTime Get Current Milliseconds From Beginning Of Day

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm trying to get the current milliseconds from the Beginning of that day. So I would like to make the following calculation. `86400000-currMilliSecondsFromBeginningOfDay`. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: currentTimeMillis() % (24*60*60*1000)

Comment: @SubinS First off thank you. Also I'm having trouble figuring out where I would put this in regards to my new DateTime() variable.

Comment: long diff = currentTimeMillis() % (24*60*60*1000); DateTime diffDate = new DateTime(diff);

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
long result = new DateTime().millisOfDay().getMillis();
```

or

```
long result = new DateTime().getMillis() - new DateTime().withMillisOfDay(0).getMillis();
```

or

```
long result = new LocalTime().get(DateTimeFieldType.millisOfDay());
```

Comment: actually getMillis() has a private access, you can use DateTime().getMillisOfDay() instead

Comment: @moretti.fabio http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/BaseDateTime.html#getMillis(). It is public

Comment: but millisOfDay() wont return a long but a 'org.joda.time.Property'

Comment: @JBoy `millisOfDay().getMillis()` returns `long`

Comment: in JodaTime 2.9.9 getMillis() is protected

Comment: @CarsonHolzheimer accoring to http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/index.html getMillis() is public in `BaseDateTime`

Comment: I mean it is protected in DateTime.Property. The result is DateTime().millisOfDay().getMillis(); gives a compile error.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the beginning of the day using [DateMidnight](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateMidnight.html) from the jodatime library.

```
long todayStart = new DateMidnight().getMillis();
```

While [DateTime constructor](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime()) will set its millis field to current value.